# Can I put more than 1 condition in if?

Tags: shell, shell-script, test

Is it possible to put more than 1 condition in an if statement?

```
if  [ "$name" != "$blank" && "$age" == "$blank" ]; then
```

Is it possible? If not how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: also has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203088/multiple-conditions-if-statement-bash-script)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `[ expression ]` (POSIX Standard) syntax you can use the following:

```
if [ "$name" != "$blank" ] && [ "$age" = "$blank" ]; then
   echo true
fi
```

But in `[[ expression ]]` syntax you can use both conditions:

```
if [[ $name != "$blank" && $age == "$blank" ]]; then
   echo true!
fi
```

**Two advantages of `[[` over `[`:**

1. No word splitting or glob expansion will be done for `[[`, and therefore many arguments need not be quoted (with the exception of the right-hand side of `==` and `!=`, which is interpreted as a pattern if it isn't quoted).
2. `[[` easier to use and less error-prone.

Downside of `[[`: it is only supported in ksh, bash and zsh, not in plain Bourne/POSIX sh.

My reference and good page to comparing `[[` and `[`: [bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: @mikeserv, Thank for your attention. I edited my post.

Comment: You mention that [ is POSIX standard.  It's worth pointing out that [[ isn't.  But if you're using other BASH features anyway, then def. use [[, it's better.  (e.g. the bash-completion project coding standards mandate use of [[ ]].)

Answer (score 4):

Yet another possibility not mentioned by [@SepahradSalour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178591/80886) is to use `-a` operator:

```
if [ "$name" != "$blank" -a "$age" = "$blank" ]; then
```

BTW, be sure to quote properly all variables **separately**.

Comment: [According to spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) *The XSI extensions specifying the -a and -o binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent. (Many expressions using them are ambiguously defined by the grammar depending on the specific expressions being evaluated.)*

Comment: @mikeserv Interesting, I didn't know that.

Comment: I suggest you modify the answer to include the comment from @mikeserv